# Click: How to customize "Error: No such command xx" error handling with Click?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a Click application, that I´m working on and I want to customize (thus override) the default behavior of Click when a command/subcommand has been invoked that is not known.

Currently there is only this error message: `Error: No such command xx` and no code after that gets executed anymore.

My initial setup is like this:

```
@click.group(cls=CustomHelpOrder)
@click.option('-v', '--verbose',is_flag=True)
def myapp_cli(verbose):
    if verbose:
         do_verbose()
    else:
         do_not_verbose()


@myapp_cli.command(help_priority=1, short_help='Foo my project')
@click.option('--bar')
def baz(bar: str) -> None:
    """
    Do something

    """
    do_something(bar)
```

So what I want to be able to do is:

- Check if this (special) exception above is raised. (Maybe if the user types `bat` instead of `baz`)
- If yes, I want to save this unknown command (like `bat` (instead of just printing the default message and exit) and use it for further processing (like passing it to various functions (as a string maybe))

I tried to 
`try:
    myapp_cli()
 except Click.Exception:
    handleExc()` but I was not able to figure out how to do this since the application just exits if the command is unknown (I think before anything can catch it; a really naive approach).
I´m wondering if I have to overwrite the default behavior somehow, but since I´m quite new to Click I don´t know how.

I´d be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own custom group. From [Click's manual](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/#command-aliases):

```py
class AliasedGroup(click.Group):

    def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
        rv = click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name)
        if rv is not None:
            return rv
        matches = [x for x in self.list_commands(ctx)
                   if x.startswith(cmd_name)]
        if not matches:
            return None
        elif len(matches) == 1:
            return click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, matches[0])
        ctx.fail('Too many matches: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(matches)))
```

In the above snippet, you can edit the following part to handle your `Command not found` case however you will.

```py
if not matches:
    # your custom logic for `Command not found` goes here
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, that was exactly what I´m looking for and worked like a charm.
I think overriding the `get_command()` is something I have to keep in mind for further projects.

Comment: Glad I could help. There are several nice things you can achieve by overriding the internal click implementation, i.e. particular command ordering, custom help messages, etc. Feel free to uptick my answer as well, if you can do that so early :D

Comment: either way, glad it helped :D